# Guzzle Http async request

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I'm trying to figure out how to make asynchronous requests with Guzzle Http.
Here is the code

```php
$page = $request->page;
            $limit = $request->limit;
            $pageStart = $page * $limit;
            $startDate = $request->start_date;
            $endDate = $request->end_date;
            $query = isset($request->search) ? $request->search : "";
            $user_token = Crypt::decryptString($company->persistent_user_token);
            $overallRecords = [];

            $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
                'base_uri' => env('BADGEBOX_BASE_URL')
            ]);

            $promises = (function () use ($pageStart, $user_token, $client, $limit, $startDate, $endDate, $query, &$overallRecords) {
                for ($page = $pageStart; $page < $limit + $pageStart; $page++) {
                    yield $client->getAsync(env('BADGEBOX_BASE_URL') . "/server/api/v1/company/overall?user_token=" . urlencode($user_token) . "&limit=1&page=$page&start_date=$startDate&end_date=$endDate&query=$query")->then(function ($response) use (&$overallRecords) {
                        dd("EXECUTED");
                        if (!empty(json_decode($response->getBody(), true))) {
                            $data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
                            foreach ($data as $record) {
                                $overallRecords[] = $record;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            })();
            $eachPromise = new \GuzzleHttp\Promise\EachPromise($promises, [
                'concurrency' => 10,
                'fulfilled' => function ($overallJson) {
                },
                'rejected' => function ($reason) {
                }
            ]);
            $eachPromise->promise()->wait();
            dd("NOT EXECUTED");
```

The asynchronous calls are never executed. Each time I execute the code, it dumps "NOT EXECUTED" that should be printed after all the asynchronous calls. Inside the asynchronous calls I print "EXECUTED", and this is never printed.
What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

The async methods on Guzzle are not being really async. You need to use $promise->wait() to send the request and wait for the result. So, you are not able to fire the request and forget about the response.

See https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1429

I tried to use a really low timeout as someone recommended, but it only fire a ConnectException.